# How to embed silverlight video in Xojo's HTMLViewer

Tags: silverlight, xojo

I'm using Xojo to code an application
I try to play silverlight videos in the HTMLViewer But it doesn't work,
like if Silverlight is not installed on the PC, And that's Because HTMLViewer can't locate silverlight folder

[Install silverlight Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9J1k.png)

When I put the application in the silverlight folder , It works fine
Is there any way to make silverlight working without putting the application there.

Thanks